# Weird error on org-capture

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture

I got my command for `Ctrl+C - c - t` (i.e. invoke org-capture) slightly wrong (i.e. missed a key or something when trying to type it). I know I got it wrong because it didn't work but instead changed something in one of my open buffers slightly (sorry, I can't remember what, and I don't know what key I mistyped). Now, if I try to use Ctrl+C-c-t again, it's giving me the following debug error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Selection owner couldn't convert" UTF8_STRING)
  x-get-selection-internal(CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING nil nil)
  #f(compiled-function (selection-symbol target-type &optional time-stamp terminal) #<bytecode 0x1fe12375f05f>)(CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (selection-symbol target-type &optional time-stamp terminal) #<bytecode 0x1fe12375f05f>) (CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING))
  gui-backend-get-selection(CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING)
  gui-get-selection(CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING)
  gui--selection-value-internal(CLIPBOARD)
  gui-selection-value()
  current-kill(0)
  org-capture-fill-template()
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

This is entirely opaque to me -- any idea what it might be and how to fix it?

Comment: If I do `M-x org-capture` the command works fine...

Comment: What does `C-h k C-c c t` return?

Comment: I restarted my computer and it fixed itself... restarting emacs didn't seem to help on its own. Sorry, this question can be disregarded. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It happens! Strange that restarting Emacs didn't help. That should be the same as restarting your computer, unless you're running Emacs in server/daemon mode.

Answer (score 1):

The command `view-lossage`, bound to `C-h l` by default, will display the last few input keystrokes and the commands run. This can be helpful when trying to untangle the consequences of a mis-pressed key.